# Merging two pandas dataframe while filtering and aggregating

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have two pandas dataframes.  One is of the following format:

```
|Customer ID | Login_Session_Start_Time | Login_Session_End_Time | 
|------------|--------------------------|------------------------|
|   1        | 2018-04-05 10:03:23      |  2018-04-05 10:15:12   |
|   1        | 2018-04-19 22:12:42      |  2018-04-19 22:45:11   | 
|   2        | 2018-04-01 08:23:14      |  2018-04-01 14:34:01   |
........
```

which lists how long each customer spent on a certain web site.  I also have another dataframe, from a different source, that lists what they bought and at what time.  It looks like this:

```
| Customer ID |  Purchase Description    | Purchase Time        |
|-------------|--------------------------|----------------------|
|     1       | Shirt                    | 2018-04-05 10:11:04  |
|     2       | Pants                    | 2018-04-01 09:35:13  |
|     2       | Shirt                    | 2018-04-01 13:12:09  |
```

.........

I need to merge the two dataframes in such a way that it tells me how many items of each kind the customer bought within each login session.  So for the example above it would look like:

```
|Customer ID | Login_Session_Start_Time | Login_Session_End_Time | Num_Shirts | Num_Pants |
|------------|--------------------------|------------------------|------------|-----------|
|   1        | 2018-04-05 10:03:23      |  2018-04-05 10:15:12   |   1        |        0  |
|   2        | 2018-04-01 08:23:14      |  2018-04-01 14:34:01   |   1        |        1  |
 .....
```

So it would involve merging while filtering (on Purchase Time being within Login_Session_Start_Time and Login_Session_End_Time), grouping (by Purchase Description), and potentially pivoting.

The only way I could think of doing this is by looping over every row of the first dataframe, then within the loop selecting a sub-dataframe of the second dataframe with a matching Customer ID and the purchase times within the limits of the first row, then grouping and pivoting that sub-dataframe, then assembling all these sub-dataframes together into the final one.  It works but it's very slow, especially with dataframes with hundreds of thousands of rows.

Is there a better way to do this?  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like merge and [`series.between()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) to compare if purchase within session:

```
m=df1.merge(df2,on='Customer ID')
m=m[m['Purchase Time'].between(m['Login_Session_Start_Time'],m['Login_Session_End_Time'])]
m=(pd.get_dummies(m.drop('Purchase Time',1),columns=['Purchase Description'],
                                                     prefix='',prefix_sep=''))
```

---

```
Customer ID Login_Session_Start_Time    Login_Session_End_Time  Pants   Shirt
0   1       2018-04-05 10:03:23         2018-04-05 10:15:12         0       1
2   2       2018-04-01 08:23:14         2018-04-01 14:34:01         1       0
3   2       2018-04-01 08:23:14         2018-04-01 14:34:01         0       1
```

Comment: Thanks @anky_91, this almost does it... two things though: 1. it's not summing the product categories (e.g., for customer 2 there should be just one row with pants = 1 and shirt = 1, and  2. m=m[m['Purchase Time'].between(m['Login_Session_Start_Time'],m['Login_Session_End_Time'])] only works for me if it's a different dataframe on the left hand side (e.g., m1 = m[m['Purchase ....

Answer (score 1):

Try using two `pd.DataFrame.groupby`s with `pd.DataFrame.join` and `pd.get_dummies`:

```
print(df.groupby('Customer ID', as_index=False).first().join(pd.get_dummies(df2, columns=['Purchase Description']).groupby(['Customer ID'], as_index=False).sum().iloc[:, 1:]))
```

Output:

```
   Customer ID Login_Session_Start_Time Login_Session_End_Time  \
0            1        20180405 10:03:23      20180405 10:15:12   
1            2        20180401 08:23:14      20180401 14:34:01   

   Purchase Description_Pants  Purchase Description_Shirt  
0                           0                           1  
1                           1                           1
```